# How can I select many rows from a table?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, layers, select

I want to create an action that select many rows from PostGIS table to show many lines in QGIS.

How can I select many rows from table with Python to add these rows in a layer?

Comment: what do you mean registers?

Comment: registers = rows

Comment: do you just want to add a postgis layer using python? can you add more clarity?

Answer (score 2):

assigning an Action Type of Python you can add multiple column field values (separated with a space), as follows:

```
u'[% "col_name1" %]' + " " + u'[% "col_name2" %]'
```

if you need to add data from numerous rows and create a new table view in QGIS, you should think about creating a plugin

Comment: Can I make a action python with that query?:SELECT * FROM pathways WHERE gid IN(SELECT mpp_path_id FROM meetingpoints_paths WHERE mpp_meeting_id = [% "gid" %])

Comment: It looks like you are using PostGIS based on the "gid" primary key.  However, if you were using sqlite/spatialite you could perform SQL using: import sqlite3; con = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.sqlite");
cur = con.cursor(); cur.execute("SELECT...the rest of my SQL statement ")

Comment: the python sqlite3 module will not handle spatialite geometries. alternately, would want to import the pyspatialite module. and use pyspatialite.dbapi2.connect("mySpatialite_DB.sqlite") to establish an object for your cursor to perform SQL on